# Justifying the choice of covariance function

Tags: covariance, covariance-function

For a Gaussian process I run I have chosen to use the Matern52 covariance function, as from research this is practical to use for physical data as it does not overally smooth the function. However is there a numerical way to prove this suits my data?

What would be the benefits of using Matern32 or Matern52, as I am quite sure that the Matern class is the correct thing to use for my data, as it allows for flexibility, whereas the other stationary covariance functions have been described to have no flexibility with regard to local behaviour and act like a prior

Comment: What is the Matern52 covariance function? Is it the same as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function)?

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that there are $M$ number of covariance functions, indexed by $m=1,\dots,M$, and we want to decide which of these $M$ offers better modelling for some dataset at hand which we denote by $\mathcal{D}$.
Dataset $\mathcal{D}$ consists of $(x,y)$ input-target pairs.

The problem can be approached with [K-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation).
First you need to choose a performance criterion.
This criterion can be e.g. predictive log-likelihood (other are possible), which tells you what the log-likelihood is when evaluated on some test data, i.e. data that you have not trained on:

$p(y_{test}) = \mathcal{N}(y_{test}|\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})
$,
where:

$\boldsymbol{\mu} = K(X_{test}, X_{train})(K(X_{train}, X_{train}) + σ^2\boldsymbol{I})^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}$ and

$\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = K(X_{test}, X_{test}) − K(X_{test}, X_{train})(K(X_{train}, X_{train}) + σ^2\boldsymbol{I})^{-1}K(X_{train}, X_{test})$.

(This equation appears as equation 2.23 in Chapter 2 in the Rasmussen and Williams [book](http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/))

K-fold cross validation divides the data in $K$ non-overlapping partitions called folds.
Let us denote the k-th fold of the data as $\mathcal{D}_k$. Let us denote the data we are left with after removing $\mathcal{D}_k$ as $\mathcal{D}_{-k}$. Note that $\mathcal{D}_k\cup\mathcal{D}_{-k}=\mathcal{D}$, that is the union of the two gives us the entire dataset back.

For each $m$-th candidate covariance function and each $k=1,\dots,K$ we perform the cross-validation as follows:

1. Train the Gaussian process (i.e. optimise its marginal log-likelihood wrt hyperparameters) on  fold $\mathcal{D}_k$. In other words, $\mathcal{D}_k$ is your training set.
2. Evaluate the trained Gaussian process on $\mathcal{D}_{-k}$ using your criterion of choice and record the value returned by your criterion as $c_{m,k}$. In other words, $\mathcal{D}_{-k}$ is your test set.

Once you have completed the above $K$-fold cross-validation for all $M$ number of candidate covariance functions, you can calculate the following estimate for the $m$-th candidate covariance function $C_m = \sum_{k=1}^K c_{m,k}$. The covariance function with the **highest** $C_m$ is the most appropriate one for the dataset $\mathcal{D}$ in question.

Finally, note that cross-validation for Gaussian process can be evaluated in a more efficient manner than presented above. For more info, please look at section 5.3 in the Rasmussen and Williams [book](http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/))